# Keeping divs from overlapping when re-sizing window and on mobile

Tags: html, css

There are many discussions about div overlapping when re-sizing the browser's window, but I still didn't find a solution that suits me.

This is the website I'm posting about: http://jsfiddle.net/uXZp2/1/

I used fixed position on the 3 divs:

```
.box1 {
    width: 23%;
    display:fixed;
    margin: 2% 54%;
}

.box2 {
    width: 30%;
    position:fixed;
    margin: 1% 15%;
}

.box3 {
    width: 25%;
    position:fixed;
    margin: 13% 17%;
}
```

I saw a discussion talking about making the div's position absolute, but won't this only make things more unstable?

How can I prevent the divs from overlapping?
Is there a way to 'tell' the divs to arrange when I re-size the window, so when the width of the window is small, the divs will arrange vertically? (this will be good for mobile browsing too).

Thanks

Comment: Read up on CSS media queries.

Comment: Also, avoid percent widths for content section like this. It's better to have a set width then scale down once a certain threshold (using `@media` queries like Diodeus suggested) is reached